# Is there a way of decreasing verbosity when running 'rails server thin' ? I only want to see logger debug messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, thin

Is there a way to decrease the amount of cruft that you look at when you're running 'rails server thin'?   Right now, I see all the sql calls and cache calls, but I just want to focus on the debug/logger messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can reconfigure the ActiveRecord logger. Edit development.rb and add the following line:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('sql.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have same settings in YAML for both development and Production, Try starting the this server with these parameters:

```
thin -e production start
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Ryan Bates' revised railscast "[The Logger](http://railscasts.com/episodes/56-the-logger-revised)" incredibly helpful.

This covers the [quiet_assets](https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets) gem, which removes asset-related logs.